# Cannot select the sandbox cube from a PowerPivot workbook as a data source for PerformancePoint

Tags: sandbox-solution, powerpivot, performancepoint

I have a bi site in SharePoint that has a PowerPivot workbook with a data model.

I have obtained the connection string and trying to add a data source but after I enter the connection string the sandbox cube is not present as an option. Can anyone help?